# SwiftUI: Why onReceive run duplicate when binding a field inside ObservableObject?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, publish-subscribe, receiver

This is my code and "print("run to onReceive (text)")" run twice when text change (like a image). Why? and thank you!

```
import SwiftUI

class ContentViewViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("pla", text: $viewModel.text)
                .padding()
        }
        .onReceive(viewModel.$text) { text in
            print("run to onReceive \(text)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the view is automatically updated as your `@Published` property in your ViewModel changes and the `.onReceive` modifier updates the view yet again due to the 2 way binding created by `viewModel.$text` resulting in the view being updated twice each time.

If you want to print the text as it changes you can use the `.onChange` modifier instead.

```swift
class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("pla", text: $viewModel.text)
                .padding()
        }.onChange(of: viewModel.text) { newValue in
            print("run to onChange \(newValue)")
        }
    }
}
```

[onChanged in SwiftUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kx9s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a `@Published` variable inside the `@StateObject` of your view, the changes in that variable will automatically update the view.

If you add the `.onReceive()` method, you will:

- update the view because you have the `@Published` var
- update it again when the `.onReceive()` method listens to the change

Just delete the `.onReceive()` completely and it will work:

```
class ContentViewViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TextField("pla", text: $viewModel.text)
                .padding()
        }

        // It still works without this modifier
        //.onReceive(viewModel.$text) { text in
        //    print("run to onReceive \(text)")
        //}
    }
}
```